# MIDI connectors / Diodes

Tags: midi

Does anybody know if the following MIDI DIN connectors will fit in a breadboard?

(or in general with 'generic' electrical components?)

[MIDI DIN](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10Pcs-PCB-Panel-Mount-MIDI-Female-DIN5-DIN-5-Pin-Jack-D501/32791217703.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.1.t95Qxz&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10000073_10065_10068_10000074_10000132_10000033_10000030_119_10000167_10000026_10000175_10000126_10000129_10000023_10000123_432_10000069_10000068_10060_10062_10056_10055_10054_10000063_301_10059_10000120_10099_10000020_10000156_10000158_10000013_10000117_10103_10102_10000016_10000114_10096_10000111_10052_10053_10050_10107_10051_10106_10000097_10000094_10000090_10000147_10000091_10000144_10084_10000150_10000101_10083_10000100_10080_10000153_10000104_10082_10000045_10081_10110_10000108_10111_10000191_10112_10113_10000197_10114_10000089_10000086_10037_10000179_10000083_10000042_10000135_10000080_10078_10079_10077_10000039_10073_10000140_10070_10000036_10122_10123_10126_10124_10000187,searchweb201603_9,afswitch_1,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel,single_sort_1_price_asc&btsid=0146bbcb-0e04-4366-8430-cef31841f51c&algo_expid=0023200f-8a8b-4111-894e-cfac21bf8947-0&algo_pvid=0023200f-8a8b-4111-894e-cfac21bf8947)

And the same for:

[Diodes](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/50-Stks-1N914-DO-35-Hoge-Conductance-Fast-Diode/32678059771.html?spm=2114.010208.3.46.AwZwQl&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_1_10000073_10065_10068_10000074_10000132_10000033_10000030_119_10000167_10000026_10000175_10000126_10000129_10000023_10000123_432_10000069_10000068_10060_10062_10056_10055_10054_10000063_301_10059_10000120_10099_10000020_10000156_10000158_10000013_10000117_10103_10102_10000016_10000114_10096_10000111_10052_10053_10050_10107_10051_10106_10000097_10000094_10000090_10000147_10000091_10000144_10084_10000150_10000101_10083_10000100_10080_10000153_10000104_10082_10000045_10081_10110_10000108_10111_10000191_10112_10113_10000197_10114_10000089_10000086_10037_10000179_10033_10000083_10000042_10000135_10000080_10078_10079_10077_10000039_10073_10000140_10070_10000036_10122_10123_10126_10124_10000187%2Csearchweb201603_9%2Cafswitch_1%2CppcSwitch_5%2Csingle_sort_1_price_asc&btsid=a0290d56-802c-4022-b235-4d24ee48ea5f&algo_expid=062424e5-c965-4a5c-9520-0b488feafecd-5&algo_pvid=062424e5-c965-4a5c-9520-0b488feafecd) to be used for MIDI in.

Comment: What does the footprint diagram in the datasheet tell you?

Comment: There are dimensions (no real datasheet), but since the pins of the Arduino breadboard are like 2 mm apart I guess it would work.

Comment: 2.54mm to be precise. It's a 0.1" grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadboards use a 2.54 mm (0.1") grid. The PCB footprint on that link uses a nominal 2.5 mm grid, which is essentially the same:
[image: MIDI jack PCB footprint]

However, those pins are rather large; it's possible that you need to rotate some pins by 90° (with pliers and brute force) to make them fit into your breaboard's holes, or that they do not fit at all. And even if they fit, they can ruin your breadboard.
You might need to file them off.

Consider using a panel-mount MIDI jack instead (which would require soldering, or leads with test clips):

[image: panel-mount MIDI jack]
(search for "5 pin DIN female jack")

---

The MIDI specification recommends a 1N914 diode, but that is only because it was written over thirty years ago. The 1N4148 is much more common now, and has the same characteristics. But this diode is used only as reverse voltage protection for the optocoupler's LED, so you can use any random fast switching diode.

---

As for the optocopler (which you didn't mention, but I'll throw in my two cents worth anyway): the PC900 was discontinued, and the 6N138 is slow. Use either the H11L1 (of which the PC900 was a clone) or the 6N137; both work best with a 1 kΩ pull-up resistor.

Comment: Thank you for all this useful information. I need to check for soldering, no experience with that either (and I'm not so handy). And thanks for the other  info too... I almost wanted to buy that specific 1N914 diode and 6N138. Sorry, I don't have much electrical knowledge (yet).

Comment: All those PCB-mount DIN jacks have the same footprint.

Comment: It's almost impossible to destroy anything if you try to solder thinner wires to the pins … :)

Comment: That's true maybe... however, the problem with thinner wires is that it the MIDI connectors will be not really placed directly in the board probably (meaning like resistor wires they will moving) and to regularly replace MIDI cables) which are heavy I hoped for a MIDI connector (or more) that can be inserted without any issue.

This one looks really much like the one I posted in my question and is prototype friendly: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9536 

Also I have to check into test clips.