# How do I properly receive MIDI with Arduino, with 6n138?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, midi, opto-isolator

UPDATE : I still can't receive MIDI as of 2019/07/01.

Here goes so far : I'm trying to follow [this schematics from instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Send-and-Receive-MIDI-with-Arduino/), using 6N138. To make it easier, I'm going to copy his schematics. 
[image]

===================================

I'm using Arduino Mega. I tried to find specific topic about this and can't find any.

The target is actually send and receive MIDI, then replace the whole Arduino Mega to ESP8266 (probably the ESP-01, or Wemos D1), but I'm afraid it is too specific.

[Here's the code so far on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/Wv8y1LUf)

Here's my work so far. 
[image]
[image: 6N138]

The diodes were replaced with LED, because I don't have one [Original guide here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/436268/do-i-really-need-diodes-to-receive-midi)
But that schematics on that thread also didn't work for some reason.

Comment: What is the Mega supposed to do? The ESP8266 can easily handle all of that on its own.

Comment: @tttapa I'm using the esp8266 only as the wifi module, mega for the rest

Comment: Define "the rest"?

Comment: @tttapa mega would receive the power, receive midi connection, send midi back, and doing everything esp8266 is only for wifi shield replacement.

Comment: The ESP8266 can easily handle MIDI connections, as well as receiving power. Using an extra microcontroller is just making everything more difficult, and is a waste of time and resources, in my eyes.

Comment: @tttapa yeah, but for now it is impossible to modify my thesis documentation. also since esp8266 has no other serial, I can't debug using serial monitor or similar and probably running blindly. that's why I consider mega at the first place. or you have another solution?

Comment: The ESP8266 has two serial ports. One of them can only transmit data. This is not a problem for debugging. On top of that, you can change the pins of the first serial port.

Comment: @tttapa but I only got the ESP01 module ... damn I should have think about this before. now I'm pretty much stuck :s

Comment: Then you should probably use the Mega. If you were to start from scratch, I would recommend a WeMos D1 mini, or similar, they are $3.50 from China, and break out all usable IO pins, and include a USB interface, so you can just plug it into your computer directly to program it, just like a normal Arduino. If you can get one in time, that would be a good solution, but you can start using the Mega for now. Either way, you'll have to program the ESP8266, you can't use AT commands for RTP-MIDI, AFAIK.

Comment: @tttapa for now I do have Wemos D1 Uno, which is kinda the same thing. But the problem is I can't change any specs, it must include mega and esp. I do have the esp with AT firmware that is compatible with [this firmware](https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/). Idk what to do next ...

Comment: Please do not edit the question in a way that makes existing answers invalid or incomplete. "How to create 220 Ω from several 1 kΩ's?" and "Can I replace or omit the 1N914 in a MIDI input?" would be separate questions. (hint: 1/1/1/1/(1+1) in parallel; and see [MIDI connectors / Diodes](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/35145/6802)) And the diode is reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to connect 6N138 to Arduino :

[image]
Schematics : 
[image]

Basically the above schematics and installation is already okay, but instead of 1k, I used 10k on 6N138 PIN 7 to GND.
VCC to 470 ohm is on PIN 6, also RX out, connected in series.

---

Just in case you want to use 6N137 :

[image]

Schematics : 
[image]

- Pin 5 of the MIDI DIN connector goes to pin 2 of the 6N137
- Pin 4 of the MIDI DIN connector goes via 330 ohm resistor to pin 3 of the 6N137 (so the 6N137 pins and the resistor are connected in series)
- You should also have a reverse connection protection diode between pins 2 and 3 of the 6N137 but I like living dangerously and rely on the diode inside the 6N137
- Pin 8 and 7 are connected to VCC
- Pin 6 is connected to RX
- Pin 5 is connected to GND
- 4.7 kohm pullup resistor between pin 8 and 6 (VCC and signal out)

Adapted from [this blog post](https://codeandlife.com/2017/09/17/5-usb-midi-adapter-with-atmega32u4/).

---

How to test it :

1. I used Arduino Mega with [this code](https://pastebin.com/9jNRYbcj).
2. I then attached the Arduino Mega to [Hairless MIDI](https://projectgus.github.io/hairless-midiserial/#downloads), then to [loopMIDI.](https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html)

   Then I read the MIDI output using [MIDIOX](http://www.midiox.com/).

---

I might update it with H11L1 / PC900 later, if I have some time. Also, I'm going to put this thread in Indonesian [in my blog](http://rinaldo.id) later.

Answer (score 3):

Most start at the [midi site at playground.arduino.cc](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MIDILibrary).  But there are numerous web sites across the Internet.  It is important to understand that the [MIDI interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) uses a [current loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop) to send and receive data.  While the Arduino normally uses voltage levels to communicate.  As such, an electronic interface needs to be built or bought to convert between these two types of signals.  [Some interface designs are simple and limited](https://www.instructables.com/id/Custom-Arduino-MIDI-Controller/).  [Others are complex and robust](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12898).

Comment: Thats a lot of read. I'll try to read them one by one. Thanks!

Comment: Use wikipedia as a reference (don't read it all, just what you need).  The playground.arduino.cc site is likely your best source.  The simple design isn't that simple and the complex not all that complex.  I was looking more for examples of simple (direct connections) and better (optically isolated) ways to convert voltage levels to current loops.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan, your question has changed a lot.  On some bread boards the power doesn't connect from one end to the other.  In such a case you need to jumper the power bus together where they don't connect.  Or move the power wires to the side where you are powering your chip.

Comment: the other power line isn't used at all.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan, that is not what I meant.  On some bread boards like yours, there are 4 power bus lines.  Two on each side.  Broken in the middle.  I see your bread board has uninterrupted blue and red lines.  So I think your bread board only has 2 power bus lines.  But it would not hurt to move where you supply power to the end of the board closest to where you use power just to check. Take a look at how the lines are painted on [this bread board](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/image/cache/catalog/New%20Components/breadboard-600x315.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of MIDI circuits and most of them are quite simple, mostly an optocoupler (6N137 or 6N138, although I had better luck with H11L1), some resistors and that's mostly it. I also added ferrite beads for EMI protection, but this is not absolutely necessary.

To test your circuit, use a lot of data (e.g. by pitchbend/aftertouch), and play notes meanwhile. If you hear stuck notes (meaning the MIDI Note Off command is missed), you know the circuit is not full proof.

Regarding libraries: the [FortySeven Effects library](https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library) is really easy to use. I used it in the beginning before I moved on to STM32 and having to write my own, but this is a good starting point.

For the schematics I based my circuit of can be found at [H11L1 optocoupler](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311889/i-cannot-get-opto-coupler-h11l1-to-work-as-midi-input).

The best way is to read the official MIDI documentation, see page [MIDI 1.0 Specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification), than search for

```
Download the Complete MIDI 1.0 Detailed Specification Document (1996) 
(Please Register! It's Free!).
```

Comment: Do you have some example schematics? That would help alot. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there has been an addendum in 2014: [Electrical Specification Update (CA-033)](https://www.midi.org/downloads?task=callelement&format=raw&item_id=100&element=f85c494b-2b32-4109-b8c1-083cca2b7db6&method=download)
It adds a specification for 3.3V systems.

Comment: @tttapa Thanks for that remark (didn't know about that addendum)

Comment: just realized nobody sells 6N137/6N138, H11L1, or everything else I found at arduino.cc that can be used as alternative.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan I buy them from AliExpress, no problems at all.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan 6N138: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/A6N138-6N138-DIP8/32843461925.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.1.3f891715EwEFhK&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10130_10547_10059_10884_10887_10696_100031_10190_10084_10083_10103_10618_10307_10820_10301_10821_10303,searchweb201603_60,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&algo_expid=59100523-2f5e-4065-af82-6c1e5b4c5d08-0&algo_pvid=59100523-2f5e-4065-af82-6c1e5b4c5d08&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan 6N137: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-6N137-DIP8-6N137-DIP-DIP-8-new-and-original-IC/32911564265.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.1.7ea619e7LGtwnu&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10130_10547_10059_10884_10887_10696_100031_10190_10084_10083_10103_10618_10307_10820_10301_10821_10303,searchweb201603_60,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&algo_expid=0090b46e-5df5-4ac3-8601-67cdbb571f94-0&algo_pvid=0090b46e-5df5-4ac3-8601-67cdbb571f94&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan H11L1M: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10pcs-lot-H11L1-DIP-6-H11L1M-Schmitt-trigger-output-at-a-high-speed-In-Stock/32892398601.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.1.36257b29TrA9ZE&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10130_10547_10059_10884_10887_10696_100031_10190_10084_10083_10103_10618_10307_10820_10301_10821_10303,searchweb201603_60,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&algo_expid=2f5ebd94-33f1-4a10-9c0c-ebcf204e1f14-0&algo_pvid=2f5ebd94-33f1-4a10-9c0c-ebcf204e1f14&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: @Michel Keijzers bro I can buy them from tokopedia and it'll arrive in 3 days. but nobody sells them locally.

Comment: okay somehow I got 6n137, but again stuck with the schematics.

Comment: This is for 6n138 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/165255/140343

Comment: For 6n137 eg https://goo.gl/images/K71nAo

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I have bought H11L1. but it still not working :( I bought it because I see you also used that.

Comment: I'm still stuck with receiving MIDI. somehow, Arduino read the input high when nothing connected. But when MIDI cable connected, arduino didn't read it.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400080/how-do-i-use-h11l1-correctly-to-receive-midi

Comment: I had some troubles with 6N137, but not with H11L1's. Make sure you use the correct resistor values (it matters for what I experienced). Also what helped me a lot was to buy a logic analyzer (about 5$), this way you can see the exact timings. If you need to see if the voltage is going up/down quickly enough you need a 'real' oscilloscope, but the H11L1 should be fast enough.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers mind checking my question there at Electronics Stackexchange to see what is actually wrong? I was very stuck ...

Answer (score 0):

I use this library with Arduino Uno (where can change bootloader):
https://github.com/TheKikGen/USBMidiKliK
And after the device is recognized from windows how a Midi device, so not need any other program to interface em.

You can use your preferred sequencer program and your arduino interface is recognized how a midi interface.

The sketch is very simple:

```
    /**********************************************************************************
  
  KIKGEN MIDI USB 
  A MIDI USB RELIABLE INTERFACE
  USB-MIDI simple converter Sketch for Arduino
       USB                           ATMEGA8U2                    ATMEGA 328P
  --------------         ------------------------------         ---------------
  IN Endpoint  o<--------o USBOUT | usbMidiKliK |  RX o<--------o (TX) MIDI IN
  OUT Endpoint o-------->o USBIN  |  firmware   |  TX o-------->o (RX) MIDI OUT   
  
  The RX/TX on the Arduino must no be crossed, as the ATMEGA8U2 is directly connected
  to the RX and TX pins.  When PIN0 (RX) and PIN1 (TX) are configured as INPUT, we
  can talk directly with the ATMEGA8U2 managing the USB, making the Arduino transparent.
  
************************************************************************************/

void setup() {

  // Make Arduino transparent for serial communications from and to USB

  pinMode(0,INPUT); // Arduino RX - ATMEGA8U2 TX

  pinMode(1,INPUT); // Arduino TX - ATMEGA8U2 RX


}

void loop() {
  
}
```

And hardware schema is this:
[image]