# How do I send MIDI properly with ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, midi

So, I've finally able to [send](https://www.instructables.com/id/Send-and-Receive-MIDI-with-Arduino/) and [receive MIDI](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56279/how-do-i-properly-send-and-receive-midi-with-arduino-with-6n138) using Arduino.

My next thing to do was sending 5 pin MIDI to rtpMIDI, and vice versa, using ESP8266, but so far I can't even send MIDI correctly. 
So far, I used [this library](https://github.com/FortySevenEffects), and it send midi without issues with Arduino Mega. But using Wemos D1, strange thing happens.

[image]
this is output of MIDI OX. Pretty sure I wasn't sending MIDI CC.

Here's the code so far :

```
#include <MIDI.h>

 // Created and binds the MIDI interface to the default hardware Serial port
 MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

 void setup()
 {
     MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);  // Listen to all incoming messages
 }

 void loop()
 {
     // Send note 42 with velocity 127 on channel 1
     MIDI.sendNoteOn(42, 127, 1);

     // Read incoming messages
     MIDI.read();
 }
```

UPDATE : Here goes the settings. 
[image]

Any reason why this happens? Please help me. Thanks!

Schematics : 
Basically I just change the Arduino to Wemos D1 Uno. 
[image]

Comment: how is it wired? MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE will use Serial on pins labeled RX, TX on Wemos, but esp8266 outputs some boot log on this RX at start.

Comment: @Juraj I updated the screenshot. the old screenshot was me trying to send MIDI using TX1, but still not working. Above screenshot were me trying to run that program, with MIDI  OUT on pin D1 (TX)

Comment: Please show a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: @CL Edited the answer with schematics. I just realized the title was wrong! :( I'm trying to send MIDI from ESP8266 (Wemos D1 Uno) through serial, to MIDI cable.

Comment: Does the Wemos run at 5 V or 3.3 V?

Comment: Wemos io pin is 3.3 V only

Comment: @CL but I run the wemos with USB cable ... does that mean 5v?

Comment: just tested the exact same sketch and schematics using Arduino Mega, and it works.

Comment: I just realized that moved the cable from 5V to Vin works! Since I only use USB connection, I don't think it should make any problems. It may broke the MIDI receiver if I'm using external power supply tho ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE : Probably not the answer you're looking for, but it works for me. 

Solution : Move the jumper from 5V to Vin. 
Why? I don't know. It just works. 

Please notice that this is Wemos D1 Uno, which has adaptor input, which can receive 9-24V. 
If you're going to use the adaptor, **IT MAY BROKE YOUR MIDI DEVICE!**
As far as I know, Vin stands for Voltage Input, and everything from the adaptor is routed there. That means if you use 24v adaptor, Vin is 24v!

I'm only planning to use USB as power supply, so yeah. it works for me. 
If you're going to use Vin with external power supply, please use voltage regulator to 5v. Better safe than sorry. 

Anyway, since I'm planning to use 6N137 to receive MIDI also on this board, here goes :

> Input voltages greater than 7 V must be avoided to preclude damage to
>   the gate oxide of the input stage. This damage is not necessarily
>   permanent, but will adversely affect the expected lifetime of the
>   circuit. The gate oxide of AHC devices is only 200 Å thick. An input
>   voltage of 7 V corresponds to a field strength over the gate oxide of
>   350 kV/cm. Although breakdown of the oxide is expected only at input
>   voltages above 10 V, electrons tunnel increasingly into the gate oxide
>   at field strengths greater than 350 kV/cm, influencing characteristics
>   of the transistors and causing failure.

Source : [this question on electronics stackexchange.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421556/what-limits-the-maximum-voltage-of-this-optocoupler-6n137)